# C++ ifstream declared as public but compiler says its a private member that cant be accessed

Tags: c++, inheritance, ifstream

Pretty new to C++ programming so be easy on me :)

I am trying to make a program for exercise reasons with C++ and design pattern for it.
This are my classes i use right now:

File.cpp-

```
 #include "File.h"
    #include <string.h>
    File::File() {}
    File::~File(void) {}
```

File.h-

```
    #pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class File
{
    public:
        //Ctor
        File();
        //Dtor
        ~File(void);

        //Opens up the file for streaming data I/O
        //virtual bool open();

    protected:      
        string _file_name;

};
```

FileReader.h

```
#pragma once
#include <fstream>

#include "File.h"

//Handles the input of our file
class FileReader : public File
{
    public:
        FileReader(string file_name_to_open);
        ~FileReader(void);

        bool isFileOpen();
        bool open();
        ifstream _in_stream;
};
```

FileReader.cpp

```
#include "FileReader.h"


FileReader::FileReader(string file_name_to_open) { 
    _file_name = file_name_to_open;
    open();
}

FileReader::~FileReader(void) { }

bool FileReader::isFileOpen() {
    return _in_stream.is_open();
}

bool FileReader::open() {
    if(isFileOpen()) {
        try{
            _in_stream.open(_file_name , ios::in);
        } catch(exception exce) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Now for some reason once i compile my main that has only

```
FileReader my_file_reader = FileReader("hello.txt");
```

i get an error

> C2248 - 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_ofstream': cannot access private member declared in class 'std::basic_ofstream<_Elem,_Traits>'

Is there a solution for this cuz i tried to so many ways to solve this but didn't found anything good so far.

Thanks

Comment: Wait, how is a file reader a file?

Comment: Also, a generic name such as `File` is begging for a name clash at some point.

Comment: When it's not in a namespace at least. With some sense, it *shouldn't* cause clashes like that.

Comment: The clang error reporting may be more helpful: `Call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'FileReader'`, followed by elaboration, `Copy constructor of 'FileReader' is implicitly deleted because field '_in_stream' has a deleted copy constructor`, and finally `Copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' has a user-declared move constructor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that in the line

```
FileReader my_file_reader = FileReader("hello.txt");
```

you try to copy `FileReader`. And because `FileReader` has a member of type `ifstream`, this member need to be copied then. But it cannot, because `ifstream`s are not copyable. (The error message from the compiler may be misleading - it does not say that you cannot copy, it says that the copy constructor is private).

Please take more care about lifetime and copying of objects in C++. For instance, instead of

```
FileReader(string file_name_to_open);
```

you should use

```
FileReader(const string& file_name_to_open);
```

Comment: That operation shouldn't copy anything, but just call that constructor. Though you're right, copying the `FileReader` class wouldn't be possible, since there's no copy constructor available for `std::ifstream`.

Comment: That worked! Awesome! :)
But i didn't really understood why that is the answer...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ C++ standard in 12.6.1 says otherwise - it is construction and then copying. Obviously it is normally optimised.

Comment: @IdoM Ifstream is part of FileReader. When you try to copy FileReader, you  implicitly copy ifstream as well, and copying ifstream is forbidden.

Answer (score 1):

Your `FileReader` class contains an `ifstream` data member which has a [deleted copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream). This causes the copy constructor for `FileReader` to be implicitly deleted as well, because the compiler generated one would otherwise be ill-formed.

In the statement

```
FileReader my_file_reader = FileReader("hello.txt");
```

you use copy-initialization, which requires an accessible copy/move constructor, hence the error. The easiest fix is to use direct-initialization instead:

```
FileReader my_file_reader("hello.txt");
```

Now your code will compile. To get the original statement to compile, you'll need to define a move constructor for `FileReader`.

```
    FileReader(FileReader&& other)
    : _in_stream(std::move(other._in_stream))
    {}
```

And might as well define a move assignment operator too

```
    FileReader& operator=(FileReader&& other)
    {
        _in_stream = std::move(other._in_stream);
        return *this;
    }
```

---

Note that in case of a C++11 compliant compiler, you don't really need to define a move constructor for your class. To have the compiler implicitly generate one for you, simply get rid of the destructor for `FileReader`, which is not doing anything useful anyway. Then your original code will compile without an explicitly defined move constructor. [Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff9a97e97b7269cd).

Another option is to explicitly default the move constructor and assignment operators.

```
FileReader(FileReader&&) = default;
FileReader& operator=(FileReader&&) = default;
```

which results in the correct behavior too. Unfortunately, neither of these are an option for VS2013. I believe this will be fixed in the next version of VisualStudio.